# How to compile GCC compiler for RISC-V

Tags: gcc, riscv

I need GCC10 in my RISCV machine, for this reason I'd like to know if it is more recommendable to download the sources and 1) compile them in the same RISCV, or 2) cross-compile those sources from a x86 machine.

In the case 1) would it be enough running

> ./configure --prefix=/path/to/build --enable-languages=c,c++

or would I need to add --target --host... parameters?

In the case 2) could you provide some hints on how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: not required but IMO you should use prefix and I believe to get other languages you will need to enable those languages.  you should not need to use target as you want a native compiler not a cross compiler and same goes for host, nothing there as you want a native not cross compiler.

Comment: Case 1 in your question should meet your needs.  Did you have issues with this approach?